# SeaSponge Report Generation

Tags: threat-mitigation, threat-modeling

I am trying out [SeaSponge](http://mozilla.github.io/seasponge/#/), a recently developed threat modelling tool which looks interesting.

The entry is similar enough to Microsoft's SDL Threat Modelling Tool. However when I click on "Reports" on the top right, it asks me to load a file. If I click on File -> Export Report as PDF, nothing happens. The tool is easy enough to use, but I seem to be failing at this stage.

How do I generate a report?